# Открытие файлов вместо сохранения .htaccess.

Tags: .htaccess

Что надо прописать в файле .htacess ?

Как открывать .bmp файлы в браузере и вообще все картинки?

Answer (score 1):

Файл .htaccess:

```
AddType image/bmp .bmp .BMP
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG 
AddType image/gif .gif .GIF 
AddType image/png .png .PNG
```